# How to build a map from a string, counting the occurrences of each letter?

Tags: string, scala, dictionary

The following method is supposed to count the number of occurrences of every char in a given string:

`def countLetters(text: String): Map[Char, Int] = ???`

For example, the input string "aabaabcab" should be mapped to

```
Map(a -> 5, b -> 3, c -> 1)
```

Here is a straightforward iterative approach:

```
def countLetters(text: String): Map[Char, Int] = {
  val h = collection.mutable.HashMap.empty[Char, Int]
  for (c <- text)
    h(c) = h.getOrElse(c, 0) + 1
  h.toMap
}
```

Is there any way to implement it without looping and explicitly allocating mutable hash maps?

Comment: Use `groupMapReduce` - As I always say, the [**Scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html) is your friend.

Comment: Wow thank you! Never been to Scaladoc. Is that easy to find what you are usually looking for?

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mre]. Please be aware that [so] is not a code-writing service, you need to show your efforts!

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Comment: I am stuck that's why there is no more code, just the basic stepik one-liner. I couldn't even start it, had no idea, now you are flagging me, because I didn't write numerous line of code, because I am stuck. Also, Scala isn't the only thing to work with. I have no time, that is why I ask these questions. I don't want a full line of code Jesus... All I would thank is a direction which for example Luis gave me and I thanked him. I don't need all these  lecturing questions. "Please be more specific and try some coding from Slacadoc, because we can't write your code here, sorry" See? @JörgWMittag

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez What's the point of linking to `root`-package? 1. It's not at all obvious that one has to look under `WrappedString`, it's a weird artifact resulting from the necessity to interoperate with Java. 2. It's not at all obvious that the `groupMapReduce` is the way to go, it's an operation that fuses three higher-order methods together, I would not expect a complete novice to recognize immediately that it's what's needed. 3. The `groupMapReduce` requires a combination of _three_ generic functions, which is instadeath for 85% of people coming from non-FP languages.

Comment: @DánielVarga In case you are wondering how to use the `groupMapReduce`, try `"aabaabcab".groupMapReduce(identity)(_ => 1)(_ + _)`. The `identity` says that each character ends up in its own group. The `_ => 1` says that each character increments the counter by `1`. The `_ + _` tells to sum the counts for characters. Compare this with `"AaAbbbb".groupMapReduce(_.toLower)(c => if (c.isLower) 1 else 2)(_ + _)` - it would group `a` and `A` together, and also count the upper-case characters twice.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I linked to the main page because there is no page for String and because I thought that linking WrappedString could be more confusing, also in this case I mean more as a general advice rather than just for this case. - Second, since when I commented OP didn't show any attempt to solve the problem by himself / herself, so I just wanted to give a small hint, not a full solution. Also, a bit subjective, but I would say that if you see the description of groupMapReduce and what each function does, then it should be straightforward to see the solution; also IIRC this is the example

Comment: @DánielVarga well this of course is subjective, but I personally do find it easy to search for what I need for _(there are something I would like to have but that would be off-topic)_. Now, I do remember that at the beginning it was quite overwhelming, my advice first search for the type you have _(there will be some exceptions with **Array** and **String**, but one learns those with time)_. Then in the page of that type search for the return type you want, there is an inner searcher that can help; also you can search for the method name or description which is very useful. Finally, read all.

Comment: Thank you @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez! Happy to hear your thoughts on the matter!

Comment: Thank you for your help @AndreyTyukin! Also thank you for highlighting my situation, because it isn't easy, just as you said!

Comment: @AndreyTyukin finally did it! Thank you!

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thank you for your help! Did it just now.

Comment: I've expanded LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez's comment into an answer. Given that it's a basic question from some catalogue of basic Scala questions, it might be useful to quite a few more people.

Comment: Thank you @AndreyTyukin very very much! Sorry if it's a problem, but here is my friends question about another topic from scala. Could you help him out?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67152199/how-can-i-map-a-weightedtree-in-scala-is-it-possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today finally did it! This is what worked for me:

`text.foldLeft(Map[Char, Int]() withDefaultValue 0){(h, c) => h.updated(c, h(c)+1)}`

Good luck on your next ones if you are reading this! ;)