# Map a "WeightedTree" in Scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, case-class

The Problem :

From this `WeightedTree` trait which I already completed, there is only one segment left, the following function:

Write a function, which recieves a `WeightedTree` as an input and returns a `Map[Char,String]`: For every char in the `Leafs` of the `WeightedTree` we write the way it leads to that specific char ( going "left" means `0` and going right means `1`), like this:

```
Inner( Inner(Leaf('a',4), 5, Leaf('c',1) ), 10, Leaf('b',5) )
     --> Map('a' -> "00", 'b' -> "1", 'c' -> "01")
```

The Code:

```scala
trait WeightedTree {
  val weight: Int
}
case class Leaf(c: Char, weight: Int) extends WeightedTree
case class Inner(left: WeightedTree, weight: Int, right: WeightedTree) extends WeightedTree

object CodeCreator extends App {
  def treeToMap( codeTree: WeightedTree ): Map[Char, String] = ???
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? This site rewards effort. Show us how you think the solution might start and we'll offer suggestions.

Comment: Dear @jwvh! Welcome and thank you for reacting to this question. Me and one of my classmate have been working on Scala tasks for a while, this one is the last of 6 tasks and all the others are already done, this one fried our brains. But after reading all this, I could think about one thing: somehow matching by the case classes and for measuring the said steps we should have an "acc" and when we reach a char, then we add it to a map after we converted the "acc" into a string? This is all I have for now. Tried looking into the almighty Scaladoc, but we got lost pretty quick.

Comment: @Daniel, that sounds like a good plan (note, you'll also need to carry the current path you descend down the tree). Now all that's left it just write the code.

Comment: Thanks @Dima for answering! Where can I find the needed functions in the Scaladoc? Should I search for map or because I want to make a char into a map should I check at the Char functions?

Comment: What functions are you looking for specifically? To add things to a `Map` you just do `theMap + (theChar -> thePath)`

Comment: @Dima I don't know at all. Maybe yes. Somehow this looks so complicated and you two just told me that my idea is great, but somehow I can't even believe it that it's good tho :D. Will try to do something, thanks for helping!

Comment: @Daniel It's not complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Friends helped out and we put this one together and it worked!

```
def treeToMap(codeTree: WeightedTree): Map[Char, String] = {

  def InnerLoop(innerTree: WeightedTree, path: String): Map[Char, String] = innerTree 
    match {

      case Leaf(ch, c) => Map(ch -> path)
      case Inner(left, _: Int, right) =>

        InnerLoop(left, path + "0") ++ InnerLoop(right, path + "1")
    }

  InnerLoop(codeTree, "")
}
```